# Read CSV to series of existing textbox in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a code to import csv to auto generated text box which was a part of my previous app. However I had to re do the whole script which involves importing csv to multiple existing textbox.

Below is my old code which worked like a charm but in this code my textbox were getting auto generated based on the numbers of value present in my csv.

```
Dim T(100) As TextBox
    Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog()
        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBox1.Text = (ofd.FileName)
        End If
        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                  FileIO.TextFieldParser(TextBox1.Text)

            MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
            Dim numer As Integer
            Dim currentRow As String()
            numer = 1
            While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                    Dim currentField As String

                    For Each currentField In currentRow
                        If (currentField IsNot "") Then

                            Dim myTB As New TextBox
                            T(numer) = myTB
                            myTB.Text = currentField
                            myTB.Visible = True
                            myTB.Location = New Point(550, 92 + (numer * 28))
                            myTB.Name = "ADBox" + numer.ToString
                            myTB.ReadOnly = True
                            Me.Controls.Add(myTB)
                            numer += 1
                        End If

                    Next

                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                     FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
           "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try

            End While
        End Using


    End Using
```

But that created a lot of issue in my app hence I had to load the values on an existing textboxes(Multiple) but I am somehow not able to.

---

> Edit1:

*** The code above creates a textbox and adds my csv values to it and what I am looking for is inject csv to existing textbox which I have created and not automatically generated text box.
For Example my code creates text box called ADUser1,2,3,4 and enters all the value but my following code which will create a textfile by fetching the values from the text box is not working because when I declare

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(aduser1, ADBox1.Text, True)
```

it says it doesn't exists because when a form loads it never created such textboxes. This is the challenge I am facing

Any help will be a great value

Thanks

Comment: "I am somehow not able to" is a wholly inadequate description of the problem. Please explain **EXACTLY** what happens, including any error messages, and where it happens, and how that differs from your expectation.

Comment: So did you have a question?  Seems like a DGV or UserControls would be easier than 100 text boxes.  1. Read with OleDB  2. Fill DataTable 3. Bind to DGV 4 Profit!

Comment: What the above code does is creates text boxes bases on the number of values I have in my csv but I want to parse the values to existing Textboxes and not new text box.

Comment: That is still not a question or even a clear problem statement.  Apparently the code you posted is not even related to the problem since it is creating text boxes

Comment: @plutonix I have edited the question for better understanding, Sorry if this issue was not posted correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that this is a *very* awkward design and should be redone, but for the purpose of answering your question...

The reason your code here: `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(aduser1, ADBox1.Text, True)` doesn't find ADBox1 is that it is not created and referenced like an object you drag on to the form.  It could be, by the way, but that is more work than dragging and naming 100+ text boxes on your form.  Nuts.  Creating the textboxes in code is better.

If you "manually" add one textbox to a form, then examine the designer-generated code for the form you will see that it created a textbox for you.  You would find something similar to `Friend WithEvents ADBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.`  This is the reason you can reference the textbox in your form code.  There is no magic here and you are technically doing the same thing in your code, here:

```
Dim T(100) As TextBox
...
Dim myTB As New TextBox
T(numer) = myTB
```

You can use the reference T(*n*) to refer to any of your textboxes. It is not clear where the WriteAllText function is but you may need to be sure `Dim T(100) As TextBox` is a form global, then change the WriteAllText line like this to get at ADBox1:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(aduser1, T(1).Text, True)
```

Comment: Thanks @gman80013 for sorting that out. This is exactly what I wanted